# Variable of imported file not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I try to import a **file** (*ChildFile*) which contains a **variable** (*testNumber*) and a **function** (*changeNumber()*). The **function** should increase the (*testNumber*) by 1. This (*ChildFile*) is imported by the **file** (*ConsumerFile*). There inside the *render* i try to call the **function** (*changeNumber()*).

**Expected Result:**
The *testNumber* increases by 1 and results 124

**Actual Result:**
The *testNumber* is 123 before and after the function call

**Information:** *I need the following structure of application -> The ConsumerFile needs to be in the structure it is. No setState possible (In my specific case I try to define something. for different classes)*

**The two files:**

*ChildFile*

```js
let testNumber = 123;

const changeNumber = () => {
    console.log(testNumber);  //123
    testNumber = testNumber + 1;
    console.log(testNumber); //124
}

var ChildFile= {
    testNumber: testNumber,
    changeNumber: changeNumber
};

export {ChildFile};
```

*ConsumerFile*

```js
import { ChildFile } from '....ChildFile';

class ConsumeClass extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        console.log(ChildFile.testNumber); //123
        ChildFile.changeNumber();
        console.log(ChildFile.testNumber); //123 -> Here it should be 124

        return (
            <div/>
        );
    }
}

export default ConsumeClass;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that? Do you want to count the number of renders your component did? It is a bad practice to have side effects in a `render()` method.

Comment: In my specific case i try to send up to a "shared-component" (own seperate npm package) some React or React-Native specific JSX components. Then they should be saved in a file from wich several classes can import their source to render. Like a config file just with JSX tags.

Comment: Okay I see but then if it is a config file it should not be mutated by a components `render()`. Although my answer answers your question I would strongly recommend not to do it like that. It is almost always a bad approach and can get you into a lot of trouble later.

Comment: Most likely you should have a parent component that injects this into the `context` so that all children can access it.

Comment: I see your point and this architecture is for sure better - But in my case the injections comes from a seperate Web / Mobile application into my package. There the "app" should have access to all components (wich need the injection) at every wanted position (different classes etc.). So the result will be every package component is available at every place in my web/mobile application. I am trying to achieve this by using HOC on package side.

Comment: Maybe my story can be done with your approach - I will check after i succesfully implemented my currend architecture (wich is pretty far at the moment :) And thanks for your help and informations ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
var ChildFile= {
    testNumber: testNumber,
    changeNumber: changeNumber
};
```

you are creating a new object named `ChildFile` with a property `testNumber` that has the value of `testNumber`. But then in your method you modify the original global variable and not the property.

This would work:

```
let testNumber = 123;

var ChildFile = {
    testNumber: testNumber,
};

const changeNumber = () => {
    console.log(testNumber);  //123
    ChildFile.testNumber = ChildFile.testNumber + 1;
    console.log(testNumber); //124
}

ChildFile.changeNumber = changeNumber;

export {ChildFile};
```

But you better should use a `class`.

Comment: You are my hero :) Yes i know handling states in a class would make much more sence. But i try to use this for different classes like a kind of "interface" and i just abstracted this use case a lot for the essence of my question.